# ASP.NET Web.API - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-web-api

After reading countless posts on Stack Overflow I figured it would hurt to throw this out there to see if anyone can help me out...

I have an ASP.NET Web.API released. I also have a Windows Service released on a ship that has a very slow Internet connection (and often none at all).

The service runs on a timer and, once the timer elapses, start off verifying that it is able to connect to my API.

```
        // Verify the remote connection via the RAC Sync Service
        public bool CheckConnection()
        {
            //using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
            //{
                HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
                log.Debug("Verifying the remote connection");
                c.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RACAPIAddress"]);
                var userID = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userID"]);


                //log.Debug("Attempting to connect using " + ".../api/RAC/CheckConnection?userID=" + userID);
                //var result = c.GetAsync(String.Format(@"/api/RAC/CheckConnection?userID={0}", userID)).Result;
                //log.Debug("Finished the attempt");
                //log.Debug("Reading the string");
                //var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();
                httpRequest.Version = HttpVersion.Version10;
                httpRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RACAPIAddress"] + "/api/RAC/CheckConnection?userID=" + userID);
                httpRequest.Headers.Add("Connection", new[] { "Keep-Alive" });
                var result = c.SendAsync(httpRequest).Result;
                var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                c.Dispose();

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    log.Debug("Received a status success code");
                    var response = JsonDeserialize<string>(content);
                    log.Debug(response);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Debug("Received Status Code:  " + result.StatusCode.ToString());
                    var error = result.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Error").Value.FirstOrDefault();
                    throw new Exception("CheckConnection() failed with message " + error);
                }
            //}
        }
```

When I use Remote Desktop Connection to view the logs I'm seeing this:

```
2015-04-01 17:02:44,546 [4] DEBUG Logger Sync Service started
2015-04-01 17:02:44,562 [4] DEBUG Logger The sleep time is set to expire every 5 seconds
2015-04-01 17:02:49,578 [4] DEBUG Logger Sleep time expired
2015-04-01 17:02:49,593 [4] DEBUG Logger Verifying the remote connection
2015-04-01 17:02:51,234 [4] ERROR Logger One or more errors occurred.
2015-04-01 17:02:51,250 [4] ERROR Logger System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at RAC.SyncService.SyncService.CheckConnection()
   at RAC.SyncService.SyncService.TimerElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
```

Oddly enough, if I attempt to call the CheckConnection function while remoted in (using a browser) everything looks normal. The ship has Internet connection and the response is returned. Any ideas out there?

I've tried (from other posts):

```
 - Adding logging (see above)
 - Removing my using block and calling dispose instead
 - Using a webRequest as opposed to httpClient
 - Adding HttpVersion.Version10
 - Including "Keep-Alive"
 - Maxing the timeouts and file sizes both on the client and server
```

Could there be a firewall preventing my call? If so, why would I be able to do it using a browser?

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: " why would I be able to do it using a browser". Is the NT service (as program) allowed out through the firewall? Does the identity assigned to the NTService have sufficient priviledges?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marvin. I'll take a look at the ship's firewall config here shortly.